# how to use worksheet function IF in vba

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

More specifically i want to use this formulae
=IF(AK3<(--"11:45:00 PM"),"Yes","No")
and delete the rows which has NO.

I am novice VBA user.Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is self explanatory. Modify it per your needs,

```
Sub timval()
If TimeValue(Range("A1").Text) < TimeValue("11:45:00 PM") Then
    Range("B1") = True
Else
    Range("B1") = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sona123 Please mark the answer as correct. Thats how you tell Thanks here at SO :)